# Check IF statment every X seconds and then run the code once

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, setinterval, current-time

I am looking for a way to check the IF statement every 1 second,

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
var cTime = vid.currentTime;
if ( cTime > 5 && cTime < 10) {
}
```

and once it is met, then run the code

```
  vid.currentTime = 15
```

I have tried **setInterval** method but assume that it is memory leak. The other thing I tried is

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
var cTime = vid.currentTime;
function skip() {
  if (cTime > 5 && cTime < 10) {
    vid.currentTime = 15
  }
  setTimeout(skip, 1000);
}
```

but it keeps on firing the **currentTime** to 15. I might have multiple if statements in the future. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Move `var cTime = vid.currentTime;` to inside the `skip()` function?

Comment: You only get `cTime` once in your code. So every time your `skip` function is called, it's always going to have the same value it had the first time. So if `cTime` was between 5 and 10 when you code first runs, it'll always be that.

Comment: _"I have tried setInterval method but assume that it is memory leak."_, why would you assume that?

Comment: You are setting currentTime to 15 hence everytime it sets the value to 15

Comment: read some comments here on SO about memory leak

Comment: Your implementation never changes cTime, over time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `setTimeout(skip, 1000);` from within your role and place in another part of the code where you make your call correctly.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
var cTime = vid.currentTime;

setTimeout(skip, 1000);

function skip() {
  if (cTime > 5 && cTime < 10) {
    vid.currentTime = 15
  }
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` will only fire once. I assume they want `setInterval`, which can then be cleared with `clearInterval`

Comment: setInterval is OK to use? I mean its not memory leak?

Comment: You need clear interval when finishes your function. 
[This article](https://reliablejavascript.com/2017/11/05/how-timer-intervals-can-leak-memory/) can help you.